# Transform each value in a list the same way

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers, and I want to have a list with exactly those numbers within apostrophes (['a', 'b', 'c']). I have no idea what the syntax should be, but my guess was this

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
for i in list:
    list[i] = f"'{list[i]}'"
```

Comment: The reason this isn't working is because you're iterating over the elements of `list`, not the indices. If you instead do `for i in range(len(list))`, this code would work fine. Another issue however, is that `list` is the name of a built-in type in Python, and by using it as a variable name, you're overwriting that type's constructor, which can lead to unexpected behavior. TL;DR: don't use `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
lists = [1, 2, 3]
for i in range(0, len(lists)):
    lists[i] = f'{lists[i]}'
print(lists)
```

another simplest option:

```
lists[i] = str(lists[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want the apostrophes to stay with the numbers? In otherwords is this *not* the behavior you're looking for?

```py
>>> print('1', '2', '4', '5', '8')
1 2 4 5 8
```

If so, then stick with the approach you started with (the other answers all just convert your numbers to strings). If you want your numbers to be displayed **with their apostrophes** then do

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in range(len(x)):
>>>    x[i] = f"'{i}'"
>>>
>>> print(*x)
'0' '1' '2'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [str(i) for i in l1]
```

Answer (score 1):

[List comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is your friend when you want to do something with every element of the list.

```
>>> a = [1,2,4,5,8]
>>> b = [str(x) for x in a]
>>> b
['1', '2', '4', '5', '8']
```